# Tomcat Inside docker has suddenly stopped responding

Tags: java, docker, tomcat

- On our production instance we run a our application on docker.
- Docker image we use is tomcat:9.0.41-jdk8-openjdk.
- One day suddenly this tomcat stopped responding.

To Troubleshoot issue we did following:

- We ran curl command from inside of container also but it still not responding.
- We thought default 200 thread config of tomcat could be issue but we tried load on similar instance on some other environment. Its thread count gone beyond and then it automatically came down.
- We also thought this could be some jvm issue. And we tried troubleshooting through [jcmd](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/troubleshoot/tooldescr006.html) tool. But the tomcat process inside inside docker was not responding.

What can be reason for this?